# Inertia for robot: Calculate by hand

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
just for my understanding. Could you tell me, if I'm right with my thinking:
If i want to setup my urdf robots inertias i just have to set the robots inertias main diagonal elements. If my center of mass is anywhere else than in the origin of my link, i change the origin of the inertia. If the mass of my link isn't equally distributed over the link i calculate a new center of mass. Is this correct or do i have to set the other elements of the inertia matrix anytime?
If I've put the right main elements in my matrix Gazebo is calculating the other elements by itself. Or isn't that right?
Best regard and thanks for your help
Max

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298886/inertia-for-robot:-calculate-by-hand/) by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2018-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here we can find a list of inertias:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_moments_of_inertia

Or use Meshlab https://www.meshlab.net/ to calculate the matrix.

---

Originally posted by [vonunwerth](https://answers.ros.org/users/34864/vonunwerth/) with karma: 66 on 2020-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0